# Sql error on simple joins on table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]Below is my simple select statement with join which gives me error

Query :

```
select a.*,r.*   from answers a join respondents r on r.id = a.respondentid
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ' '.

Answer (score 2):

I've had strange issues like this when copying and pasting queries from MS OneNote into SSMS 2014. The solution was to copy the query into notepad or outlook first and then back into SSMS. I'm sure long term my issue can be resolved by looking at the page encoding for where I store my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but probably what you can try is, close the current session and open new session and type your query manually instead of copy and paste from somewhere (try to write clean and clear query). Since, same query I was able to run

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f08d7/2)

**==Update==**

Looking at your error, which is pointing at `Line 2`. It seems there is some extra blank character, which probably causing this error.